# Is there any smart way to combine overlapping paths in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, path

Let's say I have two path names: **head** and **tail**. They can overlap with any number of segments. If they don't I'd like to just join them normally. If they overlap, I'd like to detect the common part and combine them accordingly. To be more specific: If there are repetitions in names I'd like to find as long overlapping part as possible. Example

```
"/root/d1/d2/d1/d2" + "d2/d1/d2/file.txt" == "/root/d1/d2/d1/d2/file.txt"
and not "/root/d1/d2/d1/d2/d1/d2/file.txt"
```

Is there any ready-to-use library function for such case, or I have to implement one?

Comment: Is this in Django?  Or just python?

Comment: Are these paths going to be on the same machine where the code is running?

Comment: does one always start on /root? what should the result be if both are `d1/d2`?

Comment: no django, just python; not necessarily the same machine; not necessarily starts with /root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension within `join` function :

```
>>> p1="/root/d1/d2/d1/d2"
>>> p2="d2/d1/d2/file.txt"
>>> p1+'/'+'/'.join([i for i in p2.split('/') if i not in p1.split('/')])
'/root/d1/d2/d1/d2/file.txt'
```

Or if the difference is just the base name of second path you can use `os.path.basename` to get the bname and concatenate it to `p1` :

```
>>> import os
>>> p1+'/'+os.path.basename(p2)
'/root/d1/d2/d1/d2/file.txt'
```

Comment: Works! You're genius!

Comment: This answer is great but it doesn't work if p1="/root/d1/d2/d1/d2"
p2="d2/d1/d2/d2/file.txt" instead the final string will be "/root/d1/d2/d1/d2/file.txt" instead of "/root/d1/d2/d1/d2/d2/file.txt" what I mean to say is that any folder p2 shares with p1 must be always uniquely named, if it is not then other folders with the same name will be deleted from the not in p1.split("/").

Comment: It's not working for:
p1 = "/root/b/a"
p2 = "a/b/file.txt"
p1 + '/' + '/'.join([i for i in p2.split('/') if i not in p1.split('/')])

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use [difflib.SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) followed by [get_matching_blocks](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks)

```
>>> p1, p2 = "/root/d1/d2/d1/d2","d2/d1/d2/file.txt"
>>> sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,p1, p2)
>>> size = sm.get_matching_blocks()[0].size
>>> path = p1 + p2[size:]
>>> path
'/root/d1/d2/d1/d2/file.txt'
```

Ans a General solution

```
def join_overlapping_path(p1, p2):
    sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,p1, p2)
    p1i, p2i, size = sm.get_matching_blocks()[0]
    if not p1i or not p2i: None
    p1, p2 = (p1, p2) if p2i == 0 else (p2, p1)
    size = sm.get_matching_blocks()[0].size
    return p1 + p2[size:]
```

Execution

```
>>> join_overlapping_path(p1, p2)
'/root/d1/d2/d1/d2/file.txt'
>>> join_overlapping_path(p2, p1)
'/root/d1/d2/d1/d2/file.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this works:

```
p1 = "/root/d1/d2/d1/d2"
p2 = "d2/d1/d2/file.txt"

def find_joined_path(p1, p2):
    for i in range(len(p1)):
        if p1[i:] == p2[:len(p1) - i]:
            return p1[:i] + p2

print(find_joined_path(p1, p2))
```

Note that it's a general solution that works for any two strings, so it may not be as optimized as a solution that works only with file paths.

Answer (score 0):

I just made it here looking for this answer. Hopefully it can help somone else.
Here is how i did it in Nodejs

```
const path1 = '/root/user/name/code/website/'
const path2 = './website/index.js'

const arrOfDirectories = [...path1.split('/'), ...path2.split('/')] 
// ['', 'root', 'user', 'name', 'code', 'website', '', '.' 'website', 'index.js']

const arrOfUniqueDirectories = arrOfDirectories.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
// ['', 'root', 'user', 'name', 'code', 'website', '', '.','index.js']

const jankyPath = arrOfUniqueDirectories.join('/')
// /root/user/name/code/website./index.js

const myPath = path.normalize(jankyPath)
// myPath = /root/user/name/code/website/index.js
```